# Streaming audio/video from Android

Tags: android, rtp, wowza

I am writing Android app to stream audio/video to Wowza server in RTSP interleaved mode. Using AAC and H.264 encoders. I created packetizers for both audio and video. The problem that I am facing is that when I send both streams simultaneously I am losing video stream. I only get audio on Wowza and VLC. When I do not stream audio video works just fine. This proves that my packetizers and RTP streaming code perform as expected. It looks as if I cannot send video fast enough to sustain the stream.

Similarly architected code on iOS provides stable video and audio feed.

Thank you

Comment: What kind of Android device are you using? Can you describe you architecture a little bit more, as a far as threads. It is recommended to let audio and video run on separate threads, so you utilize as much as possible of the available cores. Also, make sure that you can offload as much video-related work to your GPU instead of your CPU.

Comment: I am using Samsung Galaxy Tab 2. I have separate packetizer threads for audio and video that add to streaming queue. Then, network thread grabs packets from the queue and sends them over the socket. I now think that I maybe doing something wrong in either my SDP or when creating packets. I commented out the code writes audio packet into the socket and replaced it with Thread.Sleep(5); and it does not disrupt video on Wowza.

Comment: It looks like I have to send RTCP reports when streaming both audio and video. When I stream just video I can do without them. Very strange.